# chrome Extension , pass data to an Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

It seems like this has been asked before but I cannot get it to work.  My question is

I want to create popup dialog that contains an IFrame, (or something to the like if a better idea exists).  What will happen is the user will right click and invoke 'Make Applicant', I want to take the page the user is on, and send it to the iframe, where the iframe will do the parsing, display the results and the user will chose to edit and\or save the applicant.

In this situation I get the following error:

> Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: DataCloneError: Failed
>   to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': HTMLBodyElement object could not
>   be cloned.
>       at chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener.request (chrome-extension://ljkbppmibpdchehdfdhijcoaenhnblhm/content.js:16:30)

I am not sure how to achieve this: Pass the innerHTML to the iframe for parsing and displaying.

**background.js**

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({ 
    contexts: ['all'],
    id: 'applicantParser',
    title: 'Make Applicant'
  });

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(() => {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, tabs => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {type: 'requestParseApplicant'});
    });
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "TW Extension",
    "description" : "TW Extension",
    "icons": { 
      "16": "icon-16.png"
    },
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action" :
    {
        "default_icon" : "icon-16.png",
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [{
      "js": [ "content.js"],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
      "all_frames": true
     }],
     "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
     },
     "permissions": ["contextMenus", "storage", "activeTab", "debugger"],
     "web_accessible_resources" : ["index.html", "x.js"]
  }
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(request => {
    console.log( request );
    console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
    if (request.type === 'requestParseApplicant') {
        var bodyHtml = "<dialog style='height:70%; width:50%;'>";
        bodyHtml += "<iframe id='parseApplicant' style='height:100%'></iframe>";
        bodyHtml += "<div style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:5px;'><button>x</button></div>";
        bodyHtml += "</dialog>";
        document.body.innerHTML +=  bodyHtml;

        const dialog = document.querySelector("dialog");
        dialog.showModal();
        const iframe = document.getElementById("parseApplicant");  
        //iframe.src = chrome.extension.getURL("index.html");
        iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({call:'sendValue', value: document.body});
        iframe.frameBorder = 0;        
        dialog.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
            dialog.close();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. DOM elements can't be transferred so send just the innerHTML of an element, 2. modifying document.body.innerHTML will destroy all dynamic event listeners used by all modern pages, use insertAdjacentHTML or better yet construct the added DOM manually 3. iframe takes some time to load so you need to access its contentWindow inside iframe.onload = () => { ........ }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along with following the comment provided by wOxxOm need to add an '*' for the origin

```
const iframe = document.getElementById("parseApplicant");  
iframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html");

iframe.onload = () => { 
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({call:'sendValue', value: innerHtml}, "*"); 
}

iframe.frameBorder = 0;
```

The reason is found under:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage#Using_window.postMessage_in_extensions